# Implement half round down

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

Is there a way in Python to round the number up only if the fractional part is *larger* than a half? `round` and `math.ceil` will do this:

```
round(X.5) => X+1
math.ceil(X.5) => X+1
```

however, I want this:

```
x.500...000001 => x+1
x.500...000000 => x
```

How to do that?

I have 2.7.13 python x64

Comment: You should probably do this with [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html), where you can set `ROUND_HALF_DOWN` in the [context](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context). This will also give you more control over the precision; a floating point number from `.5` may not quite be the value you expect.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am trying that since I do not much know about it (new to python) I am getting errors when I do like the website did. can you please explain more how the proper way to use it.

Comment: *"I am getting errors"* - what errors? I'd recommend spending a bit more than ten minutes learning about it and trying things, then if you still can't solve the problem providing a [mcve] of your attempt.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it worked after playing around ... I forget to import decimal I noticed that later. however, it looks only for 15 number after decimal it is not a problem for me but I am wondering if there is a reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
math.ceil(x-0.5)
```

maps:

```
12.50 -> ceil(12.00) -> 12
12.49 -> ceil(11.99) -> 12
12.51 -> ceil(12.01) -> 13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
round(X - 0.00000000001)
```

You will need to decide how many decimal places are appropriate, bearing in mind that floats are not exact,  so for example 10000000000000000000.5 can't be represented.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer as suggested by  jonrsharpe to use [context](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context)
This is they way I used it:

```
from decimal import *
x =5.500000000000001   # it is the number wanted to round, however only takes 15 number after decimal for me
ctx= Context(prec=1, rounding=ROUND_HALF_DOWN)
y = ctx.create_decimal(x)
```

However, I do not know if it is going to work with everybody.
probably there is a better way to put it.

Answer (score -1):

```
import math
while True:
    num=input("num: ")
    num=float(num)
    new_n=round(num,0)
    if (float(new_n)-0.5)==num:
        print(num-0.5)
    else:
        print(new_n)
```

output:

```
num: 4.5
4.0
num: 5.5
5.0
num: 6.6
7.0
num: 5.5001
6.0
```

well I had to do some thinking but this should do what you want

Comment: Try entering 5.5.

Comment: `round` in Python 3.x uses `ROUND_HALF_EVEN`, not `ROUND_HALF_DOWN`. In Python 2.x, which the OP is apparently using, it's `ROUND_HALF_UP`.

Comment: it is still the same problem

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser changed the code now it is better no issue with 5.5 or anything

Comment: @legendisback yes it works fine, however, I found the answer using context, but I can see the logic you used which can be a good case study for me to learn python. Thank you.